# STM32 Scan Conversion gets only channel in last rank

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, adc

I'm trying to read multiple ADC channels on a STM32F302VC. I wanted to exploit the scan conversion mode, in order to have a fast sequence of reading. After I set every channel with the .ioc file, by having Continuous Mode and Scan Conversion mode activated, plus a succession of channels defined in the ranks, I use the common ADC_PollForConversion and ADC_GetValue due to check for the end of conversion and get the obtained value.

The issue is ADC_GetValue, looking at the DR of the ADC, always get only the last value.

```
    // Start ADC1 conversion
    if (HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1) == HAL_OK)
    {
        // Wait for conversion to complete
        if (HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1, HAL_MAX_DELAY) == HAL_OK)
        {
            // Read ADC value
            adc1_value[i] = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
            HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_10);
        }
    }

    // Stop ADC conversion
    HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc1);
```

with "i" being an incremental value, used to fill the adc1_value

What should I change to obtain values coming from each different ADC channel?

Edit:

@Lundin

The ADC1 is initialized as following:

```
  hadc1.Instance = ADC1;
  hadc1.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_ASYNC_DIV1;
  hadc1.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
  hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = ADC_SCAN_ENABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;
  hadc1.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_NONE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START;
  hadc1.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = 4;
  hadc1.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV;
  hadc1.Init.LowPowerAutoWait = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.Overrun = ADC_OVR_DATA_OVERWRITTEN;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Configure the ADC multi-mode
  */
  multimode.Mode = ADC_MODE_INDEPENDENT;
  if (HAL_ADCEx_MultiModeConfigChannel(&hadc1, &multimode) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Configure Regular Channel
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_2;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_1;
  sConfig.SingleDiff = ADC_SINGLE_ENDED;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_1CYCLE_5;
  sConfig.OffsetNumber = ADC_OFFSET_NONE;
  sConfig.Offset = 0;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Configure Regular Channel
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_4;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_2;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
```

I left out the last two channels because redundancy.

@pmacfarlane I am not using DMA since I have problems between DMA interrupt and FreeRTOS scheduler, I might open a separate thread for that.

Comment: Obviously it matters a lot how you have initialized the ADC. The various "HAL" function calls here don't really say anything at all.

Comment: It's quite common to use DMA if you're doing a scan conversion. Maybe your code isn't reading the values out fast enough. It's also not clear if you are calling `HAL_ADC_Start()` for each channel. That would be a mistake.

Comment: @Runzolf, should `if (HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1, HAL_MAX_DELAY) == HAL_OK)` be `while (HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1, HAL_MAX_DELAY) != HAL_OK);`?

Comment: You need to use dma or interrupts. Only one channel in polling mode. Data register is being overwritten by  the results of the conversions - trhat is the reson why you read only the last one

Comment: @Lundin added the initialization as you asked.

Comment: @pmacfarlane added comment about DMA: I have some problems using it together with the FreeRTOS scheduler. I have not used HAL_ADC_START() for each channel, I tried to sample at different speeds and in fact I have the Data Register overwritten by the last value. If I use debugging sometimes I catch the previous values.

Comment: @Runzolf DMA is the only reliable way to achieve what you want. It might be possible using interrupts, but even then it wouldn't be robust. Especially since you are not dividing the ADC clock at all, and are using a very short sampling time. You need to think about how many clock cycles it will take for the ADC to generate the next sample. Can you really call HAL functions quicker than that? Probably not, since they are so bloated. And if you have other tasks that can preempt you, you'll have no chance. Fix the DMA problems.